# how to automatically pop-up webpage after connecting to a wifi hotspot? through iptables?

Tags: wifi, iptables

Is it possible to use iptables for auto pop-up after connecting to a wifi?

I am trying to create a wifi hotspot that will force an advertisement page after a user successfully connects to my wifi router. though not necessarily authenticating them. I just wan't an immediate pop-up after logging in.. is this possible w/ iptables?

Comment: The term you want to Google is [*captive portal*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal).

Answer (score 1):

I have something like this in my iptables ( in the nat table ) on my router.

```
-A PREROUTING -i br1 -j BR1_GUEST_LIST

-A PREROUTING -d 10.254.0.1/32 -i br1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -i br1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8081
```

And my forward table:

```
# Allow DNS
[0:0] -A INPUT -i br1 -p udp -m udp --sport 67:68 --dport 67:68 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -i br1 -j BR1_GUEST

# Forbid self access on externals
[0:0] -A BR1_GUEST -d 192.0.2.1/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
[0:0] -A BR1_GUEST -d 192.0.2.2/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

# Allow web access this box
[0:0] -A BR1_GUEST -d 198.51.100.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A BR1_GUEST -d 198.51.100.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Allow DNS
[0:0] -A BR1_GUEST -d 198.51.100.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

# And web access on this IP too.
[0:0] -A BR1_GUEST -d 10.254.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8081 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A BR1_GUEST -d 10.254.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A BR1_GUEST -j BR1_GUEST_LIST
[0:0] -A BR1_GUEST -j REJECT
```

Mine is a login page, but after the login, the users MAC addresses get stuck in BR1_GUEST_LIST ( on both nat and forward tables )

```
-A BR1_GUEST_LIST -m mac --mac-source ff:aa:bb:cc:dd:ee -j ACCEPT
```

You could add visitors to that list once they've seen or clicked past the ad.

Comment: Can you add some explanation so that its easy for newbies to use this?